# How do I increase the amount of supported Unicode characters on my Debian desktop?

Tags: linux, debian, fonts, unicode

Here is a list of characters I see squares with instead of the proper characters. The list is extracted from [here](https://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample-3-2.html):

### CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B

...

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTpjx.png)

There is a large amount of characters I can't see. I'm currently using the latest version of Chrome on Debian 9.8 and I have installed Bitstream Vera and [Twemoji Color Font](https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font#install-on-linux) to see if it solved the problem (it doesn't).

How do I increase the amount of supported Unicode characters for my display?

---

I should also add that it is currently impossible for me to properly visualize Zalgo texts due to this same problem. Instead, floating squares are displayed around the emojis and the text.

Example texts ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98aT5.png)):

T̸̴̺̺͇̝̬̫͔̙͠H͚I̴̧͏̬̞̖͕S̭͜ ̴̲ͅI̷̶̯͖̤̥̻͝Ş͕͍̭̣̟̼́̕ ͏̗̥̰̗̺̩̦ͅE̶̘̲̬͖̜̟͙̭̖X̛͕̘͈̥͙̪͎T̶͚̕R҉̻͍̜È̙͎̙̟̥̕ͅM̹̲̘͇̤̦͜͡Ę̣̼͈͈̳͝ͅL̗͔͝Y̘̭͉̳ ̗̞͎͘D̯̦̺̯̟̟̥̕͜ͅA̷҉̸̖̥͖͇͖N̷̵̖̱̣̘͎G̻͙͚̳̰̱͓̱̫͘E͏̠͉̻̰̪̲̰͖̭R҉͏͍̼̗̥ͅO̞͖̮̳͓U͍̣̫̤̼͟S̭̘ ̠̯̰͇̞Ţ͇̯̙O̷͚̱͕̦̪̪͉̺͞ ͏̨͉̫̬̠̞̘̩͍ͅO̙̜̫̯̘U̸̩̰̦̮̜̞R̮̤̝̜͉̖̘̞̞ ̛͉̠̤̟̼̭͉͞M̝͈͕͍͖͇͘͠Ò̸͈̝N͏͏̥̦̰̞̖ͅÒ̬̮͔̤̥͕̻ͅP̫̝̟̖͓̙̟͜Ọ̷̭͠Ļ̸̴̜͎Y̷̴̜͖͈̹̫͈̞̬
̡̪͕̜͙

H̦̲͖̻̣͓͕̹͆͛̅͂̀́ë̱͕͎̞͈̪̥̖̙́͛̉̿ͨḹ͛̎̑ͩͬ̏ͭͩl̠̭̣͍̋͒̀͊ͧ̋ͪ̐ͨo̝̦͇̼̭̞̹̅̾͆ͣͯͪ͂̐ ͚̘ͯͅl̖̰ͭͤ̆̆̆̽i̪̤̞̬͔̭͓͗̿̓̃͌̌͊t̮̤̱̬̘͎̃̆ͧ̿ͧt̩̪̘̘ͣ͂ͦľ̬̬͈̼̌͌ͪ̄ͭe̺̙̜͚͇̙̠̲̗ͪ̔͑͛̀̅ͧ͊ ͈͉͂͑̂ṭ͈̤̥͋̇̇̆͗ͫ̏h͉̬̣̜̳͍͍̗̿̇̈̏ͨ̔i̘̪̯̞̳̜ͥ͋ͅn̼̙̫̮̼̼̗̙ͩͩ͗̋̓ͅg̯͎̝̺̩ͣ̐̎ͩ͐ͅ.̣͓̟͉̖̟͖̌ͨ̏ͅ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's clarify first:

There is no way to *increase the amount of supported Unicode characters* in Debian as a default Debian supports **all** unicode **characters** (code points).

What you are missing is one (or several) **fonts** that have **glyphs** (images) for the required characters (code points).

One (free) font that covers a huge amount of glyphs of HAN ideograms is [BabelStone Han](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html)

Installing such ttf font should increase the coverage of the whole HAN range.

But *CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B* is [a Unicode block containing **rare** and **historic** CJK ideographs for Chinese, Japanese, Korean, and Vietnamese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_B).

Given that those ideographs are **rare** and **historic** it is not surprissing that the font given above only covers 15.9% ( 6,879 / 42,711 ) of that range. Even installing the full list of 49 fonts (some expensive) listed [in here](https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/block/cjk-unified-ideographs-extension-b) the coverage will only get up to 47.21% ( 20,162 / 42,711 ) of that range.

So: don't expect Debian (nor anyone else) to cover the whole range.

There are some other fonts that contain glyphs in that range as [listed in this page](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/cjk_unified_ideographs_extension_b.html).

---

For zalgo text (using many combining characters, also known as combining marks):

The simplest way is to download and install a sufficiently large font, such as [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/)

Comment: Thank you. I installed two fonts that solved the problem partially. I will revisit this answer if I have more problems in the future that need other fonts. I installed `fonts-croscore` to be able to display the Zalgo, and I installed `fonts-hanazono` to be able to see the hanzi characters.